# How can i retrieve proxy information from phone ? android.net.Proxy.getPort isn't working

Tags: android, proxy

my application tries to retrieve proxy information from app using android.net.Proxy and than set the information on my restemplate . 
It works fine on nexus one but in other phones like Samsung Galaxy it retrives the value -1 for the port , the host works fine.

I've looked everywhere and i cant find out why is returning this value even after i set the proxy port  value on the phone , i also read that this method  android.net.Proxy.getHost() and
android.net.Proxy.getPort() are deprecated , so my question is :

How can i retrieve proxy information from phone ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
String port = System.getProperty("http.proxyPort");
String hostName = System.getProperty("http.proxyHost");
```

Comment: It does not work , it retrieves null values from the properties

Comment: Hmm sorry. That seems to be the way Android is recommending you to perform this task. Does that work on the Nexus One?

Comment: The older way (deprecated one) works nicely on the nexus one , but it does not work on sansung galaxy ..

Comment: Okay, then I really don't know. I was only going off of what Android documentation suggested.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811698/getting-wifi-proxy-settings-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Much more detailed answer here: [Getting WiFi proxy settings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811698/getting-wifi-proxy-settings-in-android/13616054#13616054)

---

I'm currently doing the following:

```
    private static final boolean IS_ICS_OR_LATER = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;

    ...

    String proxyAddress;
    int proxyPort;

    if( IS_ICS_OR_LATER )
    {
        proxyAddress = System.getProperty( "http.proxyHost" );

        String portStr = System.getProperty( "http.proxyPort" );
        proxyPort = Integer.parseInt( ( portStr != null ? portStr : "-1" ) );
    }
    else
    {
        proxyAddress = android.net.Proxy.getHost( context );
        proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getPort( context );
    }
```

However this only works for System Wide Proxy Settings on pre-3.1 devices, as WiFi AP specific Proxy Settings were not implemented yet. And the System Wide Proxy can not easily be set through the standard Android UI.