# Getting WiFi proxy settings in Android: ConnectivityManager.getDefaultProxy() is always null

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the current WiFi HTTP proxy settings in API 28.

Code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ProxyInfo pi = connectivityManager.getDefaultProxy();
        editText1.setText(pi != null ? pi.getHost() : "null");

        WifiManager wifiManager =
                (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        pi = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks().get(0).getHttpProxy();
        editText2.setText(pi != null ? pi.getHost() : "null");
    }
}
```

Outputs the following when a proxy is configured:

[image: activity view]

The second text field is filled by an over-deprecated code:

[image: deprecated code]

Why the deprecated code works but not deprecated one - doesn't?

I checked an old similar thread [Getting WiFi proxy settings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811698/getting-wifi-proxy-settings-in-android) but its suggestions are too outdated and I can not use external libraries (moreover, the mentioned library in that thread doesn't exist anymore).

PS: Here is the proxy configuration in the wifi settings:

[image: wifi proxy settings]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the cross icon on the WiFi connection that appears when the system tells "Connected, no internet". The proxy is accessible, internet works, but Android OS thinks that the connection is broken. To workaround this, remove proxy settings from the WiFi settings, save changes, reconnect wifi, and add proxy settings again. After that, proxy settings can be read successfully by the first method thru the `getDefaultProxy` method. But after some time it will be reverted back to the "No Internet". It seems like Android OS doesn't believe that the internet is connected when debug proxy is configured.